# How to toggle Fugitive status window

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-fugitive

Fugitive provides a `:Git` commands that opens a window with basically the output of `git status`. To close it, I need to switch to that window and close it, which is tedious.

How do I toggle this window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Fugitive's `:Git` window always opens in the topleft position, we can simply do `:1close` (or even shorter `:1clo`) to close that window without switching to it.

But if we do want to a toggling functionality for it, we can utilize 'fugitive_status' window property/variable that Fugitive sets for its `:Git` window. If any of the opened windows have this variable, we close it; if none of the windows have it, we invoke `:Git` command.

```
function! ToggleGstatus() abort
  for l:winnr in range(1, winnr('$'))
    if !empty(getwinvar(l:winnr, 'fugitive_status'))
      exe l:winnr 'close'
      return
    endif
  endfor
  keepalt Git
endfunction
nnoremap gs :call ToggleGstatus()<CR>
```

N.B. I used `keepalt` command so `:Git` doesn't affect the alternate buffer variable `#` (see `:h alternate-file` and `:h :keepalt`).